# html Text content not updating

Tags: javascript, html, css, addeventlistener

I'm trying to make an incremental game. but when I test it out the game doesn't increment clicks, everything looks fine. So what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance :)

**JavaScript Code(in separate file)**

```js
//Unused or copied code
//  mass += energy;
//  btn.innerText = mass + "mass";
//DOM
let btn = document.getElementById("btn");
let img = document.getElementById("img");

//Variables
var mass = 0;
var energy = 1;
var version = 0.1 + 'oab';

//El(s)
img.addEventListener('click', e => {
  mass += energy;
  let btn.textContent = mass + " Mass";
});
```

```html
<input type="image" id="img" src="assets/sun.jpg" name="button" alt="clicker" width="250" height="250"><br>
<h1 id='btn'>0 Mass</h1>
```

Comment: This doesn't look like Java code -- could you be mistaking Java for JavaScript, a completely distinct language?

Comment: probally, im fairly new

Comment: The distinction is important as there is no sense getting the *wrong* experts to review your question

Comment: Thanks! I updated the tags

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use let to assign `.textContent`

```js
let btn = document.getElementById("btn");
let img = document.getElementById("img");

//Variables
var mass = 0;
var energy = 1;
var version = 0.1 + "oab";

//El(s)
img.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  mass += energy;
  btn.textContent = mass + " Mass";
});
```

```html
<input type="image" id="img" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/" name="button" alt="clicker" width="400" height="100" />
<br />
<h1 id="btn">0 Mass</h1>
```

Comment: It worked at first, but when I went in to add upgrades it stopped working

Comment: @EthanBelcher That does not mean that the answer is wrong. You code is not correct. Plz share it so I can help you further...

Answer (score 0):

@ManasKhandelwal

**HTML code:**

```
  <body>
            <h1 id="btn">0 Mass</h1>
            <h1 id="nrg">1 Energy</h1>
            <br><br><br>
            <input type="image" id="img" src="assets/sun.jpg" name="img" alt="clicker" width="250" height="250">
      <br><br>
                <div id="spacerock">
            <h1>Space Rock</h1>
            <div id="rest">
                <img src="assets/space_rock.png" alt="space rock" width="32" height="30">
                <div id="l&c">
                    <h2>Cost: 50</h2>
                    <h2>LvL: 1</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      <script src ="js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
  
</html>
```

**Javascript Code:**

```
img.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    mass += sra;
    btn.innerHTML = mass + ' Mass';
});

spaceRock.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (mass >= srp) {
        if (srl <= 12) {
            energy += sra;
            srl += 1;
            srp = srl * 50;
            sra += 1.5;
            nrg.innerHTML = energy;
        } else {
            nrg.innerHTML = 'MAX';
        }
    }
});

const text = document.innerHTML();
const btn = document.querySelector('btn');

const img = document.querySelector('img');
const nrg = document.querySelector('nrg');

const spaceRock = document.querySelector('spacerock');
```